# Best way of getting updates on intermediate simulation results

Tags: software

I will be interfacing our fluid dynamics code with an optimizer. I expect the optimization process to take 3-4 days for any decent decrease. But I will want to have a look at the intermediate results for trends and to make sure that things does not blow up, both at the optimizer level and at the fluid dynamics level.

One way is to go to individual folders containing results for all the run and check them periodically. Another way it to write a code which does that for me and print a result as single place. Another thing that can be done and is more visually appealing is to generate a html file using a script which make some fancy graphs using data from all the run etc.

I wanted to ask whether solution to this task already exists? And what is the most preferred way of doing this? Also any particular data format which will be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

There are no general solutions to this problem, but there are lots of workflow tools that might help you orchestrate your process. Whether you choose to compute derived quantities or make pictures to establish the progress of your runs is up to you to determine based on what's most helpful to you in your work.

You might look at:

- [Kepler](https://kepler-project.org/)
- [VisTrails](http://www.vistrails.org/index.php/Main_Page)
- [Taverna](http://www.taverna.org.uk/)
- and many more.